# How to set dynamic criteria for endpoint with the Element API plugin?

Tags: plugin-elementapi

How can I set the criteria for an endpoint based on the current category view?

My `elementapi.php` looks like this where I can pass the slug of a category url to force a return of entries from the slug name.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
$criteria->slug = "albania";
$category = $criteria->first();

return [
                'endpoints' => [
                    'directory.json' => [
                        'elementType' => 'Entry',
                        'criteria' => [
                                'section' => 'directory',
                                'limit' => null,
                            ],
                        'paginate' => false,
                        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                            return [
                                'title' => $entry->title,
                                'mapinfo' => $entry->mapaddress,
                                'url' => $entry->slug
                            ];
                        },
                    ],
                    'directory-category.json' => [
                        'elementType' => 'Entry',
                        'criteria' => [
                            'section' => 'directory',
                            'relatedTo' => ['targetElement' => $category],
                            'limit' => null,
                        ],
                        'paginate' => false,
                        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                            return [
                                'title' => $entry->title,
                                'mapinfo' => $entry->mapaddress,
                                'url' => $entry->slug
                            ];
                        },
                    ],
                    'seafarers-directory/<entryId:\d+>.json' => function($entryId) {
                        return [
                            'elementType' => 'Entry',
                            'criteria' => ['id' => $entryId],
                            'first' => true,
                            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                                return [
                                    'title' => $entry->title,
                                    'url' => $entry->url,
                                    'body' => $entry->body,
                                    'mapinfo' => $entry->mapaddress
                                ];
                            },
                        ];
                    },
                ]
            ];
```

I tried setting the criteria category slug name with

```
craft()->urlManager->getMatchedElement();
```

but it always returned nothing.

Can a dynamic category be set for the criteria from the existing url like the dynamic entry is?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this out.
By using the variable slug in the endpoint URL I was able to listen for the category in the currently viewed category slug and pull the data i needed for my google map. The trick is to typomake the end point a function - i was trying to set the criteria outside of the endpoint which is, in retrospect, silly.

```
'locations/<slug:{slug}>.json' => function($slug) {

                        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
                        $criteria->slug = $slug;
                        $category = $criteria->first();
                        return [
                            'elementType' => 'Entry',
                            'criteria' => [
                                'section' => 'directory',
                                'relatedTo' => ['targetElement' => $category],
                                'limit' => null,
                            ],
                            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                                return [
                                    'title' => $entry->title,
                                    'mapinfo' => $entry->mapaddress,
                                    'url' => $entry->slug
                                ];
                            },
                        ];
                    },
```